# JavaScript: How to average json array based on specific keys / fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, average, reduce

I would like to average specific keys like

```
const users = [
  { name: 'Adam', age: 20, country: 'France', weight: 100 },
  { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'Germany', weight: 100 },
  { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'India', weight: 200 },
  { name: 'Adam', age: 40, country: 'France', weight: 200 },
  { name: 'Oliver', age: 28, country: 'France', weight: 200 }
];
```

Keys 'age' and 'weight' are averaged based on the keys 'name' and 'country'

```
output = [
  { name: 'Adam', age: 30, country: 'France', weight: 150 },
  { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'Germany', weight: 100 },
  { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'India', weight: 200 },
  { name: 'Oliver', age: 28, country: 'France', weight: 200 }
];
```

Keys that are not defined are removed:

Keys 'age' and 'weight' are averaged based on the key 'name'

```
output = [
  { name: 'Adam', age: 29, weight: 150 },
  { name: 'Oliver', age: 28, weight: 200 }
];
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: More information? I can't understand what do you want? Delete ''country'' key from object or?

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group it by the wanted keys and get the averages for every wanted property for each group.

```js
function getAverages(array, groupKeys, averageKeys) {
    var groups = {},
        result = [];

    array.forEach(o => {
        var key = groupKeys.map(k => o[k]).join('|'),
            group = groups[key];

        if (!group) {
            groups[key] = { count: 0, payload: {} };
            group = groups[key];
            averageKeys.forEach(k => group[k] = 0);
            groupKeys.forEach(k => group.payload[k] = o[k]);
            result.push(group.payload);
        }
        groups[key].count++;
        averageKeys.forEach(k => group.payload[k] = (group[k] += o[k]) / group.count);
    })
    return result;
}

const users = [{ name: 'Adam', age: 20, country: 'France', weight: 100 }, { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'Germany', weight: 100 }, { name: 'Adam', age: 28, country: 'India', weight: 200 }, { name: 'Adam', age: 40, country: 'France', weight: 200 }, { name: 'Oliver', age: 28, country: 'France', weight: 200 }];

console.log(getAverages(users, ['name', 'country'], ['age', 'weight']));
console.log(getAverages(users, ['name'], ['age', 'weight']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions like filter, map, and reduce to accomplish these specific goals.

To ensure keys exist, you filter entries that miss those keys:

```
// Keep entries that have the age property
const cleanedUsers = users.filter(x => x.age)
```

To get the average age of the users, you then can take the cleaned array and reduce it to a single number, and then divide it by the length of the array. This can be done in a single line of code.

```
const average = users.filter(x => x.age).reduce((acc,x) => acc + x.age, 0) / users.length
```